# Ionic app with api not running on real device

Tags: ionic3, slim

I develop an ionic app with api, I add allow-control-allow-origin in my chrome so its running perfectly in browser but in real device my app dont run. I think api didnt read by my app. its displaying my toast "please check your network connection" someone help me. sorry for my english
this is my code

```
    let apiUrl = "http://mywebsite.com/api/public/api/";

    @Injectable()
    export class AuthServiceProvider {
      responseData:any;

    constructor(public http: Http) {
     console.log('Hello AuthServiceProvider Provider');
    }

    postData(credentials, type){
     return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        let headers = new Headers();
        this.http.post(apiUrl+type, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers}).subscribe(res=>{
            resolve(res.json());
        }, (err)=>{
            reject(err);
        });
     });
     }
  }
```

and my login.ts

```
login(){
let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    spinner: 'crescent',
  content: 'Please wait...'
});
loading.present();
this.authService.postData(this.userData,'login').then((result) => {
this.responseData = result;
if(this.responseData.userData){
  console.log(this.responseData);
  localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.responseData));
  loading.dismiss();
  this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
  }
  else{
    loading.dismiss();
    loading.onDidDismiss(() => {
        const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: 'Invalid Email or Password!',
          duration: 3000
        });
        toast.present();
    }); 
  }
}, (err) => {
  loading.dismiss();
  loading.onDidDismiss(() => {
        const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'Please Check Your Internet Connection',
      duration: 5000
    });
    toast.present();
  });   
});
}
```

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: i edit my codes above sir. i think my app didnt read my api

Comment: On what device are you running your code ?

Comment: my code is running perfectly in my browser but in my real device it doesnt

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn’t run on your device ? Try to use a device debugger to see what is your error. If you’re running on Android, use chrome debugger (go to chrome://inspect with google chrome) or with safari inspector if you’re running on iOS

Comment: i mean my app is running on real device. but at the backend i think my app cant read properly my api. i have login in my device and i cant login because my api didnt responding. im not really good at english sorry

Comment: As I told you, try to debug your app with a browser inspector to see in the console what is your error

Comment: . I dont have any Errors when im on browser sir its working fine